# How can i store a volley response in a variable out the request?

Tags: java, android, httprequest, android-volley, httpresponse

i've searched and tried many solution to this problem, but any of these worked for me. I want to store the JSONObject that i fetch with a volley request in a variable out the request. I always print empty object... My last piece of code is this:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;

public interface RequestListener{
    public void onRequest(JSONObject obj);
}

public static JSONObject risultato = new JSONObject();

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dashboardViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);


    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(root.getContext());
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("tipoRichiesta", "mie");
        data.put("id_utente", "1");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final JSONObject[] ris = {new JSONObject()};

    RequestListener listener = new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRequest(JSONObject obj) {
            risultato = obj;


        }
    };

    Log.d("data che invio:", data.toString());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.1.5/getRichieste.php", data, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // do things on response
            listener.onRequest((JSONObject)response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Errore", error.getMessage());
        }

    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    Log.d("result", risultato.toString());
```

Thanks!

Comment: [here's my guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: Thanks! I thought was a scope problem, instead it was a race condition